# How can I find the the position of the k-th occurrence of a character in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm writing a program which takes a string, a single character and an integer number *k*, then it finds the k-th occurence of given character in given string.

I think the code is correct but the code below doesn't give proper results.

```
char ch[100];
char character;
int n;
cout << endl << "Type a string of characters : ";
gets_s(ch);
cout << endl << "Enter a single Character : ";
cin >> character;
cout << "Enter the event : ";
cin >> n;
if ( func_1( ch,  character,  n)!=-1)
    cout << endl << n << "th event is in the position number  " << (ch, character, n)<< endl;
else
    cout << "Event couldn't be found  ." << endl;
}

 int func_1(char ch[], char character, int n)
 {
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    do
    {
       i++;
    } while (ch[i] != '\0');

    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < i-1;)
    {

        if (ch[j] == character)
            c = c + 1;

        j++;
    }

    if (c == n)
        return j-1;

    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "This integer number shows the event of that single character happened in the blocks of the array"? I'm completely lost as to what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: @JerryCoffin
For example your string is : Jerry Coffin
your single character is : f
your integer number is : 2
The result must be that the second 'f' is located in the 10th block of the array .

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow this morning, but that doesn't seem to clarify anything to me.

Comment: May I **strongly** suggest that you do not use indented statements for `if`s instead of braces (`{}`)? Indentation has a *huge* track record of failing to proper show what should be executed and allows for bugs far easier (at least in a language like C where indentation is often ignored)

Comment: @Avery
I'm agree with you .

Comment: The word you want is not "event", it's "occurrence", it might save a headache to some people :)

Comment: @e23k - So you're saying just to find the nth occurrence of a certain character in a string?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
Exactly

Comment: @Drax
Thanks for mentioning 
Excuse me for my poor English .
I'm working on it

Comment: So, given a string *s*, a character *c* and an integer *k*, you want to find the index of the *k*:th occurrence of *c* in *s*? If I were you, I would first solve the problem of finding the first occurrence. Then consider how you could loop that solution.

Comment: @molbdnilo
Can you write down your idea in codes please ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in **func()**:

Look at:

```
do {
    i++;
} while (ch[i] != '\0');   // ouch will loop forever if ch[] is "" !!
```

Either use a normal while,  or write `i=strlen(ch);`

Then, when you write this you count all the occurences:

```
for (j = 0; j < i - 1;) {   // loop unil end of string  
    if (ch[j] == character)
        c = c + 1;            // But if there are several occurences, he will count them all 
    j++;
}
```

For example, if there are two 'e' in ch[] and you look for the first occurence,  when the loop is over, there will be 2 in c, so it will fail !

Rewrite this loop:

```
for (j = 0; j < i - 1 && c!=n;j++) {   // loop unil end of string => put j++ here for clarity, and exit if you've fount what you've searched
    if (ch[j] == character)
        c++;             
}
```

But there is also a display issue in you main programme.  Look at:

```
if (func_1(ch, character, n) != -1)
    cout << endl << n << "th event is in the position number  " << (ch, character, n) << endl;
```

Ok he'll print that he found something,  but he will always print n, because (ch, character, n) is not a function call but the comma operator which returns the most right element.

Rewrite this as:

```
int result = func_1(ch, character, n);
if (result != -1)
    cout << endl << n << "th event is in the position number  " << result << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have many problems inside the code, but the most relevant part is this one:

```
for (j = 0; j < i-1;)
{

    if (ch[j] == character)
        c = c + 1;

    j++;
}

if (c == n)
    return j-1;
else
    return -1;
```

You count the number of occurrences in the whole string, and then check if you were lucky enough to have the exact number of occurrences needed inside the whole string.

What you actually want to do, is to check if you found *n-th* occurrence inside the loop, like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < i-1;)
{

    if (ch[j] == character)
        c = c + 1;
    if (c == n)
        return j;  
    j++;
}
```

Then you probably want to read up on [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), [strchr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), and fix other bugs in your code.